# error in removing divs containing ng Grid using remove() method in Angularjs

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-grid

I have few tabs (Angularjs UI boot strap tabset) in my UI, when I click any tab, I remove the previously drawn charts and tables in a div, using remove() method in Angularjs. The divs contains c3 charts, ng grid tables, etc. It is working fine when it comes to remove the divs if they contain c3 charts, but if the div contains ng Grid tables I am getting error. The following is my code and error, How can I fix it?

Tabs Code:

```
<tabset>
    <tab heading="***" snap-toggle ng-click="openSnapDrawer();"> </tab>
    <tab ng-repeat="eachTab in d3DashboardTabs" heading="{{eachTab.tabName}}" select="createDashboradsforeachTab(dashboardData, eachTab)"> </tab>
    <tab heading="GoogleMap" select="drawGoogleMap(dashboardData)"> </tab>
</tabset>
```

Controller Code:

```
$scope.createDashboradsforeachTab = function(dashboardData, eachTab) {

    // Remove All the Previously Drawn Charts/Tables in chartsDiv
    var chartDivs = angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.chartsDiv'))

    var cntChartDivs = chartDivs.length;

    if (cntChartDivs) {
        while (cntChartDivs > 0) {
            angular.element(chartDivs[cntChartDivs - 1]).remove();
            cntChartDivs = cntChartDivs - 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'off' of null
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (https://localhost/dashboard3/js/d3angular/ng-grid.debug.js:1008:31)
    at HTMLDivElement.jQuery.event.dispatch (https://localhost/js/jquery-1.9.1.js:3074:9)
    at HTMLDivElement.elemData.handle (https://localhost/js/jquery-1.9.1.js:2750:46)
    at Object.jQuery.event.trigger (https://localhost/js/jquery-1.9.1.js:2986:12)
    at jQuery.fn.extend.triggerHandler (https://localhost/js/jquery-1.9.1.js:3683:24)
    at removePatch [as remove] (https://localhost/dashboard3/js/d3angular/angular.js:2247:21)
    at Scope.$scope.createDashboradsforeachTab (https://localhost/dashboard3/js/controllers.js:699:54)
    at https://localhost/dashboard3/js/d3angular/angular.js:10694:21
    at Scope.isolateScope.(anonymous function) [as onSelect] (https://localhost/dashboard3/js/d3angular/angular.js:6565:26)
    at TabsetCtrl.ctrl.select (https://localhost/dashboard3/js/d3angular/ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.12.0.js:2993:17)
```

My controllers.js:699 line is:

```
angular.element(chartDivs[cntChartDivs - 1]).remove();
```

Comment: Manipulating the DOM within an AngularJS controller is one of the worst things to do. Why do you need to remove the previous charts from the DOM?

Comment: remove the model data not the DOM elements and @AnidMonsur is totally right, don't manipulate the DOM from controller

Comment: I agree with both @ Anid Monsur and  charlietfl.  But what is the alternative? If you suggest me to write a  custom directive for this, I greatly appreciate if you can provide me some sample remove directive code reference to remove dom . Right now, writing directives is way out my head as started Angularjs recently. It takes some more time for me to pick it up, or if you can suggest any fix for my code to work, I  will be saved for now. Thanks.

Comment: Answer to @Anid Monsur question, on each tab click  I need to create multiple number of charts with different data. Just to have clean one, I am deleting the old charts and compiling the new template in controller, angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('.snap-content')).append($compile(template)($scope)). I know this is also worst practice which I am aiming to replace with directives in future.